# How to dynamically call the ACF data of a post in popup with different buttons?

Tags: wordpress, popup, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I created a post for each member separately with CPT UI. And I will call the data of the posts with ACF in a popup when a button is clicked. But what attribute should I add to this button so that it can call the ACF data of the desired member when clicked? What is the logic of this?

[Here it shows the data of the current page instead of the post I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kFIq.png)

However, I want the data of the desired page to be shown in a popup in the current page.